# Comparing RDF literals in AllegroGraph Prolog in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, rdf, allegrograph

I am trying to compare the objects of two triples in a knowledgebase. I have connected the knowledgebase through ACL client (Allegro CL Enterprise edition 9.0) and written the following code:

```
(select (?s ?threshold ?NameMatch)
    (q- ?s !mynamespace:hasNameMatch ?NameMatch)
    (q- !mynamespace:hasNameMatch !mynamespace:hasThresholdValue ?threshold)
    (setq return (if (>= (?NameMatch ?threshold "true" "false")))     
   (pprint ret))
```

My Knowledgebase includes the following triples

```
Subject             Predicate             Object
ns:hasAddressMatch  ns:hasThresholdValue  "60"
<../729277>         :hasNameMatch         "70"^^xsd:double
```

I am trying to compare the `?threshold` with value `"60"` and `?NameMatch` with value `"70"^^xsd:double`, and I expect the result `"true"`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:prolog]?

Comment: @false: probably because it uses an embedded Prolog in Lisp for the Knowledge Base.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Definitely out of scope of tag.

Comment: @user3061324: are you sure the `IF` statement and the variables are correct...?

Comment: @false: why? An embedded Prolog is no Prolog? The `?var` are the logical vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RDF data, things that aren't blank nodes or IRIs are literals.  Literals may be a plain literal (a string with no additional information), a string with a language tag, or a lexical form (string part) with a datatype (an IRI).

In your data, the literal with lexical form `"70"` has a datatype which you've censored, but I assume is supposed to be `xsd:double`.  I.e., the value is `"70"^^xsd:double`, which is the double precision floating point number 70.  Your other literal value `"60"` is just a plain literal.  It doesn't *really* make sense to compare those two values, since one is a number and one is a string.

You have two options though:

1. You could do a string comparison with the plain literal `"60"` and the lexical form of `"70"^^xsd:double`, in which case you'd use [`string<`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) or [`string-lessp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm), depending on whether you want case sensitivity or not (since these are strings of digit characters, it probably doesn't matter).
2. You could assume that the plain literal `"60"` has a lexical form that's legal for an `xsd:double`, do the appropriate conversion, and then compare `"60"^^xsd:double` and `"70"^^xsd:double` as numbers with `<`.

I'd suggest that, if possible, you clean up your data (but this might not be an option if it's coming from somewhere else) so that you can do a numeric comparison with `<` as in (2), but without needing to do the conversion at comparison time.

In addition to those RDF concerns, your Lisp code also has some issues.  `if` takes three arguments (the third is optional, though). The first is a test condition, and the second and third are forms that get evaluated depending on whether the first evalutes to true or not.  In your code, `if` is only getting one argument:

```
(if (>= (?NameMatch ?threshold "true" "false")))
    -------------------------------------------
```

This is trying to call `>=` with one argument, and that's the

```
(?NameMatch ?threshold "true" "false")
```

which would be a function call to the function named `?NameMatch` with three arguments (`?threshold`, `"true"` and `"false"`).  What you probably want here is:

```
(if (>= ?NameMatch ?threshold) "true" "false")
```

(Of course, you may still need to modify the test as described above.)

Comment: Many Thanks Joshua  for your answer. My both values are typed double. I found the issue as now I am converting the value via upi->value function in ACL client.Now It does not give the error but it does not show "TRUE"

Comment: @user3061324 What does `upi->value` on these values return?  What are you using to compare the resulting values?

Comment: I have changed double to integer and it return 80 and 60. However it does not give the result "true"